# Failing to generate dynamic Checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I am working on a WPF where I need to dynamically generate Checkboxes 16 times.

**XAML:**

```
<Checkboxes Height="14" Command="{Binding CheckboxesGen}" Margin="0" Name="checkBox1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

Using above way, It will be inefficient if I write down this Checkboxes 16 times and have individual Button Click Command for them. I would ideally want to generate them 16 times and have one common method in my viewmodel class as follows:

```
private ICommand mCheckboxesGen;
    public ICommand CheckboxesGen
    {
        get
        {
            if (mCheckboxesGen== null)
                mCheckboxesGen= new DelegateCommand(new Action(mCheckboxesGenExecuted), new Func<bool>(mCheckboxesGenCanExecute));

            return mCheckboxesGen;
        }
        set
        {
            mCheckboxesGen= value;
        }
    }

    public bool mCheckboxesGenCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void mCheckboxesGenExecuted(some INDEX parameter which gives me selected Checkboxes )
    {
        // Have a common method here which performs operation on each Checkboxes click based on INDEX which determines which Checkboxes I have selected
    }
```

I had faced the same situation in my C++ app. I had done it in my C++ app as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 16; j ++)
    {
        m_buttonActiveChannels[j] = new ToggleButton();
        addAndMakeVisible(m_buttonActiveChannels[j]);
        m_buttonActiveChannels[j]->addButtonListener(this);
    }

//Checking which Checkboxes is clicked
unsigned bit = 0x8000;
for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(0 != (value & bit)) //Value has some hardcoded data
    {
        m_buttonActiveChannels[i]->setToggleState(true);
    } 
    else
    {
        m_buttonActiveChannels[i]->setToggleState(false);
    }

    bit >>= 1;
}
```

Hence using this generates it 16 times and has one method which performs operation based on `index i`.

Using a similar approach or any other approach, How can I achieve it in my wpf app? :)
Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfObjectsThatRepresentYourCheckBox}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Checkbox Content="{Binding DisplayText }" Checked="{Binding Checked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

you would need to populate your collection on objects on load or when a command was executed, then you could react to items being checked in the model that you create for it..

```
public class CheckBoxClass
{
 public int Index {get; set;}
 public string DisplayText {get; set}
 private bool _checked;
 public bool Checked 
 {
   get { return _checked;}
   set {
        _checked = value
        doSomethingWhenChecked();
       }
}

ObservableCollection<CheckBoxClass> CollectionOfObjectsThatRepresentYourCheckBox = SomeMethodThatPopulatesIt();
```

this is a much cleaner way to do this and instead of generating the controls you will be just binding to a list of your objects that will be represented by a check box.

Comment: Yeah you are right :) But this generates checkboxes one above the other. Ideally as per requirement I should have all 16 chckbxs in one row itself :)

Comment: use ItemsPanelTemplate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspaneltemplate.aspx

Comment: @StonedJesus That's fine, see updated code - that should display how you want it :)

Comment: @StonedJesus you would need to set the index when you add your item to the ObservableCollection - How about using a For loop and set the index to the current loop index?

Comment: @Steoates: Well I am done with setting the index when I add item. How do we go ahead with forloop?

Comment: @StonedJesus I'm not entirely sure what your asking, I would guess that these check boxes will map to some state of the object, the index doesn't need to be an Int, it could always be an ID instead - the only reason its there is just to provide some unique ID.. if you need it that is

Comment: @Steoates: Have a look at my for loop in code. You will understand what I mean :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18522/discussion-between-stonedjesus-and-steoates)

Answer (score 0):

Define a viewmodel for the checkboxes, this class will have an Index property and the command implementation based on it. Add an ObservableCollection of checkboxes viewmodels to your current viewmodel. In the view add an ItemsControl bound to this collection with a proper ItemTemplate. You can now add as many checkboxes as you want dynamically in the viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks :) Would appreciate if you pls elaborate with a sample code :)